# Change View on successful registration using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have three UIViewControllers ViewController, HomeViewController and RegisterViewController using storyboard. Their Storyboard ID is Login, Home and Registration respectfully. There is a button on RegisterViewController view named 'Register'. After successful registration i want to go to home page i.e., HomeViewController. How to do it. Please help I'm new to iOS.
thanks

Comment: Its simple. Just present your "HomeViewController" after sucessfull registration. like :: UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NameOfYourStoryBoard" 
                                                     bundle:nil];
HomeViewController *objHomeView = 
           [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“Home”];

[self presentViewController:objHomeView 
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:nil];

Comment: It's not working. Error occurs there.

Comment: Incompatible pointer types sending 'HomeViewController *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'   This error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
- (IBAction)buttonRegister:(id)sender {
      UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
     // replace Main with your storyboard name
     HomeViewController *homeVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
    [self.view addSubview:homeVC.view];
}
```

Comment: It's showing an error, property view cannot be found in forward class object 'HomeViewController'

Comment: import HomeViewController in this class
#import "HomeViewController.h"

Comment: Did it worked? Your error removed by importing class. Let me know if there is an issue

Comment: another error   'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle.....' My storyboard name is Main.storyboard here.

Comment: Jus add Main (Replace Main.storyboard with Main). No need to write .storyboard

Comment: Use as it is the above

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)yourRegisterButtonAction:(id)sender
{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEUGE_NAME" sender:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a navigation controller and do this.

```
   -(IBAction)registerButtonTapped:(id)sender{
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        HomeViewController *viewController =(HomeViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
```